# Cannot change ownership of folder owned by nobody

Tags: permissions

After a forced reboot a particular folder in my home directory is owned by `nobody`. I am trying to change that to `root` but I get the following

> chown: cannot read directory ‘databases/’: Permission denied.

This is the command I `sudo chown -R root databases/` and this is the permission of the folder:

> drwxrwx--x 36 nobody nobody 4096 Jul  9 08:10 databases

How can change the ownership?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `mount | grep home`? This will allow use to check the filesystem type as well as confirm it's not mounted read-only.

Comment: VTC+Delete since it's abandoned. Another poster can then try with their own situation, perhaps more proactively

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the file system in which your folder resides. 
It could be that your file system either does not support Linux permissions/ownerships (e.g. NTFS) or that something corrupted when you forced the reboot.
This might be a silly suggestion, but have you tried also with `chown -R root:root databases/` (either with `sudo` or directly as root)?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the attributes for the folder are proper. Do this:

```
lsattr
```

It should give some output like this:

```
----i--------e-- ./databases
```

Now, if the `i` attribute is present, it means that the folder is not editable. So, you should remove that attribute and keep only the `e` attribute. To do this, do:

```
sudo chattr =e databases/
```

After this, you can now change the ownership.

Comment: I tried run `lsattr` but I have `lsattr: Permission denied While reading flags on ./databases`. I also tried with sudo but with the same resuts